# passing object from servlet to jsp (returns null)

Tags: jsp, servlets, null

I know there are many topics with this issue but i cannot fix mine..
 I have a class in which i define an object

```
public class UserBean{

    private String string1;
    private String string1;

    public String getString1(){
           return String1;
    }

    public String getString2(){
           return String2;
}
```

Then in my Servlet i have:

```
    //Create my Object1 and some other code...

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    // some code...

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    request.setAttribute("PassingObj", Object1);
    RequestDispatcher disp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/mypage.jsp");
    disp.forward(request, response);
```

then in my jsp:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

    <% ArrayList<UserBean> cis = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("PassingObj"); %>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${cis}">
          <c:out value="${cis.getString1}" />
    </c:forEach>
```

and then i get null.. 
 My Object has arrays inside... i tested to print the same thing in the console inside the servlet and it works fine!! thanks..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue, you are setting *request* attribute, and accessing it from *session*. Of course you won't get it.

Secondly, you can't access the variable set in scriplets in EL. In fact, you don't need to, and you shouldn't use scriplet at all. In fact, it doesn't make sense to set that scriplet variable in your case.

Thirdly, you should use the loop variable `item` to access the bean variables. Also, you should access the field directly using it's name, and not `getString`. Also, check your *getters*, you are returning wrong variable. That won't compile.

In all, you can directly iterate over the list using *JSTL* and *EL*:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${PassingObj}">
      ${item.string1}
</c:forEach>
```

Note, you don't need to use `<c:out />` tag. Directly using `EL`, will achieve the same functionality.

And finally, please give your *request* attribute and `UserBean` fields some sensible name.

Comment: you said "First issue, you are setting request attribute, and accessing it from session. Of course you won't get it." i didnt get it... can you expalin me plz?
As for the names i use more sensible names. i just put theses names here...

Comment: @yaylitzis. Well, if you set the attribute in `request`, you can only get it from `request` right? Not from `session`. They are both different scopes.